# Select from IEnumerable<T> to IEnumerable<Quantity<T>>

Tags: c#, linq

Say for example I have a collection like so:

```
Apple
Banana
Banana
Apple
Apple
Pear
Banana
Grape
Orange
Pear
```

As you can see, there are multiples of some of these items. What I want is a collection which shows the item, and it's quantity. For example, the data above, would appear something like this:

```
Apple (3)
Banana (3)
Pear (2)
Grape (1)
Orange (1)
```

I have created a class...

```
public class Quantity<T>
{
    public Quantity(T item, int count)
    {
        Item = item;
        Count = count;
    }

    public T Item { get; private set; }
    public int Count { get; private set; }
}
```

I'm presuming it can be done with LINQ using some sort of `Select` statement that would project from `IEnumerable<T>` to `IEnumerable<Quantity<T>>`...that being said, I've not the foggiest how to start :-| ...any ideas?

Comment: You start with `GroupBy` :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the inputs are `string` then you can use the following GroupBy with Select projection.

```
var result = food.GroupBy(fruit => fruit)
                    .Select(fruit => new Quantity<string>(fruit.Key, fruit.Count()));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`GroupBy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534493(v=vs.100).aspx) method provided by LINQ. It works by grouping items where a specific value is the same into seperate sets.

See the following example:

```
var fruits = new[] { "Apple", "Apple", "Banana", "Banana" };
var quantities = fruits.GroupBy(
  (f) => f,
  (f) => f,  
  (f, fs) => new Quantity<string>(f, fs.Count())
);
```

To see this example in action, check out the following [.NET fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/D6onxT).